# How to turn-off Anti-aliasing when convert video into gif file with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-quality, animation

I want to know how can i turn off Anti-aliasing when i convert video into gif file with ffmpeg, Actually i want ouput  in 100% pure aliased gif animation.  like this sample image [image: aliased vs anti-aliased]

Here i try this but i did not get the results as i expected.

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -t 5 out.gif`

Any help will be appreciated.